# Como printar o tabuleiro corretamente no jogo da velha

Tags: python

```
    def imprimeCampo(campo):
            c = 0

            for i in campo:
                    if c % 3 == 0:
                            print ("")
                            c = 0
                    print (i),
                    c += 1

            print ("\n")

    def ganhou(simbolo, campo):
            if campo[0] == simbolo and campo[1] == simbolo and campo[2] == simbolo:
                    return 1


            if campo[3] == simbolo and campo[4] == simbolo and campo[5] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[6] == simbolo and campo[7] == simbolo and campo[8] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[0] == simbolo and campo[3] == simbolo and campo[6] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[1] == simbolo and campo[4] == simbolo and campo[7] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[2] == simbolo and campo[5] == simbolo and campo[8] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[0] == simbolo and campo[4] == simbolo and campo[8] == simbolo:
                    return 1

            if campo[2] == simbolo and campo[4] == simbolo and campo[6] == simbolo:
                    return 1

    def velha(campo):
            if '_' not in campo:
                    return 1


    import random


    campo = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_']

    jogador = random.choice((0,1))

    if jogador == 1:
            sVC = 'X'
            sPC = 'O'

    else:
            sPC = 'X'
            sVC = 'O'

    print ("Voce e' %s" % sVC)
    print ("O Pc e' %s" % sPC)

    while 1:
            if velha(campo):
                    imprimeCampo(campo)
                    print ("VELHA")
                    break
            if jogador:
                    imprimeCampo(campo)

                    while 1:
                            vc = int(input())

                            if campo[vc] == '_':
                                    break

                    campo[vc] = sVC

                    jogador = 0

                    if ganhou(sVC,campo):
                            imprimeCampo(campo)
                            print ("VC GANHOU")
                            break

            else:
                    imprimeCampo(campo)
                    while 1:
                            pc = random.randint(0,8)

                            if campo[pc] == '_':
                                    break

                    campo[pc] = sPC

                    jogador = 1

                    if ganhou(sPC,campo):
                            imprimeCampo(campo)
                            print ("PC GANHOU")
                            break
```

Comment: No caso, não estou conseguindo printar o tabuleiro de forma certa. Se alguem puder dar uma dica. Agradeço desde ja.

Comment: Executei seu código e ele funcionou normalmente... Não entendi qual é o problema. Qual IDE você está usando? Eu usei Python 2 e IDLE.